# Upload to Amazon S3 and Calling Amazon Cognito Identity from Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I am trying to follow the steps to upload files to Amazon S3 from an iOS app.

According to the AWS iOS SDK docs, before uploading, it is required to authenticate the app users for secure access to AWS resources via my backend server:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html#providing-creds

What is the right way to call the AWS Cognito Identity **GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity** service from a rails (version 4.1) server?

This service is not part of the aws-sdk gem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cognito is only supported via the the [v2 Ruby SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby).

Here is a minimal example for `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` using the v2 SDK:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
cognito = Aws::CognitoIdentity::Client.new(region:'us-east-1')
resp = cognito.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity(
           identity_pool_id: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID', 
           logins: {'MY_PROVIDER_NAME' => 'USER_IDENTIFIER'})
```

- **IDENTITY_POOL_ID** - The ID of your pool
- **MY_PROVIDER_NAME** - The provider name you configured on your identity pool
- **USER_IDENTIFIER** - The unique identifier for this user in your system

The response (when successful) will contain an `identity_id` and `token` for your user, which can be passed back to your mobile application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, through it is not clear how to use the cognito identity module. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Can you you elaborate what you are looking for? Are you looking for an introduction to using the Ruby SDK or specifically Cognito?

Comment: Thank you Bob, my problem is that the current aws-sdk gem (version 2.0.6.pre) does not contain the implementation for Aws::CognitoIdentity::Client

Comment: @asafam Please make sure you've actually installed and are using the correct version as the code I included above was against the current version of the v2 AWS sdk gem.

Comment: I followed the installation notes on the ruby aws gem page. My logs indicate I am using: 
    Using aws-sdk-core 2.0.6
    Using aws-sdk-v1 1.57.0
I guess this relates to another question. Thank you.

Comment: I have followed the above instructions and get the error "An identity pool only supports one developer provider. The logins provided here have more than one developer profile" - Any ideas?

Comment: @Ríomhaire are you supplying more than one key/value pair in the logins map? Are you sure the value for 'MY_PROVIDER_NAME' matches the provider name you supplied in the identity pool configuration? If you are still encountering issues, I recommend opening a new question.

Comment: Cheers for the reply @BobKinney - I have outlined my use case on the Cognito Forums https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=587853&#587853