# Should I instantiate an object every request or once upon app launch?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rack, aws-sdk

In my Rack app, I need to use an [AWS Cognito Client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26808756/242933) for signup & login requests.

Should I initialize:

1. a separate client (assigned to a local variable inside the `call` method) for each request?
2. one client (assigned to a global variable outside the `call` method) for all requests?

Concerns:

1. Speed & cleanup: Is initialization time fast? Is the client automatically destroyed at the end of each request? I studied the source code but didn't grasp the metaprogramming.
2. Thread safety: Is this option thread safe? I have Puma configured to use multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito is most useful when you delegate to your end users obtaining credentials and making calls to AWS themselves, so it's not usual to need Cognito in the server side.

**Edit:** If you want to implement developer authenticated identities, then it definitely makes sense to use a Cognito service client so you can call **GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity**. It is safe to do so from a multi-thread environment, because no state at all is saved between invocations of that call.

Comment: I thought you needed Cognito on the server to support [developer authenticated identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking about developer-authenticated identities and my answer was not accurate. I've edited my answer to reflect that.