# How to use devise and aws cognito in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, amazon-cognito

I'm using rails 3.2 and devise 3.2.3. I'm trying to use AWS Cognito Developer Authenticated Identities and find myself lost on how to do it.

Our users have to be authenticated. How can I use Custom for the Authentication provider in the Identity pool if I'm using Devise gem?

I'm already using aws-sdk v1 and installed the v2 gem to support cognito.

```
gem 'aws-sdk-resources', '~> 2'
```

I saw this post [Upload to Amazon S3 and Calling Amazon Cognito Identity from Rails server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704404/upload-to-amazon-s3-and-calling-amazon-cognito-identity-from-rails-server) but don't know where to place the block below if it is correct.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
cognito = Aws::CognitoIdentity::Client.new(region:'us-east-1')
resp = cognito.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity(
           identity_pool_id: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID', 
           logins: {'MY_PROVIDER_NAME' => 'USER_IDENTIFIER'})
```

Comment: I'm hoping to hear from Rails people who use AWS. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using something like the code below in our API:

```
if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
    #get the cognito token and id
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Cognito doesn't have an end to end example for developer authenticated identities in Ruby, however there are [Android and iOS examples](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en).

Generally, the flow is to create a Cognito Identity client, and that client sends a request to your backend. The backend will communicate with Cognito to get/generate an ID and token, and send those back to the client. The client will then use that id and token to get credentials. The above blog post and the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/) have some lower level details.

In terms of the code snippet, the second line is creating the Cognito client. The third communicates with Cognito, the response from which will be used to send the ID and token back to the client.